# Visibility ArrayList inside function

Tags: android

I've a problem with an ArrayList. I declare the ArrayList inside a class. I populate it inside the OnCreate method. On the Oncreate method i call a function and inside this function i access to the ArrayList, but it's empty.... It's starnge:

```
public class List_themeActivity extends Activity{

    String[]    array ;
    ArrayList <String>bdd_checked = new ArrayList<String>();

    private SQLiteDatabase bdd;
    private ListView listView_listebase;

    ListView msgList;
    ArrayList<MessageDetails> details;
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_theme);

        List<String> bdd_checked = readList (this, "animal");                                       

        initDB("LSPCC4.db");
        [...]
    }
}

protected void initDB(String BD_NAME){
    int lg_bdd_checked=0;   
     lg_bdd_checked=this.bdd_checked.size();
}
```

Someone can help me? thx

Edit:
Sorry the ArrayList is empty in iniDB().

Thanks to maqjav, the problem is solved, i've done this:

Before:

```
List<String> bdd_checked = readList (this, "animal");
```

After:

```
bdd_checked = (ArrayList<String>) readList (this, "animal");
```

and i've casted due to readList():

public static List readList (Context context, String prefix)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("YourApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

```
int size = prefs.getInt(prefix+"_size", 0);

List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>(size);
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    data.add(prefs.getString(prefix+"_"+i, null));

return data;
```

}

Comment: Where is it empty? In `initDB()`? And show us `readList()` method's code.

Comment: Did you verify if readList is returning correct values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating 2 different ArrayLists:

Here (local in your class):

```
ArrayList <String> bdd_checked = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And here (local in your function onCreate):

```
List<String> bdd_checked = readList (this, "animal")
```

Modify the second line to:

```
bdd_checked = readList (this, "animal")
```